# Can't access time helper from view

Tags: php, cakephp, time, helper

```
<?php echo $time->timeAgoInWords($row['Forum']['modified']); ?>
```

The modified column from which I am receiving the data is formatted as MySQL datetime.
I am trying to use the above code to get a time value shown formatted with `timeAgoInWords()`, but I keep getting this error.

> Undefined property: time [APP\views\forums\view.ctp, line 60]

I don't understand why I am getting this error.

Comment: in cake1.3 and above you should be using echo $this->Time->...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Your controller or app_controller, Put below code,

```
var $helpers = array('Form', 'Html', 'Javascript', 'Time');
```

Comment: perfect catch !! About to answer the same :)